# Is there a way extending existing interface implementations with less code than this?

Tags: java, java-8

Let's assume we have an interface "I" and n implementations of "I" named "C1" to "Cn". Let's assume further the interface as well as the implementations reside in an external library which cannot be changed. Finally, let's assume we are using Java 8.
Now we want to extend the functionality of all implementations of "I".
If "I" were changeable, we could simply add new methods with default implementations to it, as Oracle did to roll out the streaming API. Unfortunately "I" is not changeable.
My current solution is as follows:
Create a new interface "IX" which extends "I" and contains the required new methods as default implementations to it.
Because "C1" to "Cn" do not implement "IX" but "I", we need Implementations "CX1" to "CXn" to make use of the new functionality. This is the part I do not like. I'd prefer a way to create the implementation on the fly like anonymous classes.
Here are some code examples to illustrate my approach:

```
// Instantiate existing "C9" implementation of "I"
I object = new C9();

// Definition of interface "IX"
public interface IX extends I {
  default void newMethod() {
    // Do something
  }
}

// Example definition of implementation "CX9"
// Off course, this needs to be done for all "C1" to "Cn".
public class CX9 extends C9 implements IX {}

// Instantiate extended implementation "C9"
IX object = new CX9();
```

Because the definitions of "CX1" to "CXn" do not need any body implementation at all, I consider those boilerplate  and would like to get rid of them. I actually would prefer something like the following.

```
IX object = new (C9 implements IX)() {};
```

That, off course, is no valid Java code. The idea is to create an anonymous class which is based on an existing class ("C9") implementing an additional interface ("IX"). Is there a way to do this with standard Java?
I definitely want to do this with standard Java and without byte code manipulation. Off course, I could use wrappers or dynamic proxies but "I" and the "C"s define lots of methods. Therefore I would end up with even more boilerplate code.
I admit this question is purely academic, because in the end it's about getting rid of only one line of code per implementation of "I". But I'm still interested in the possible solutions.
If you like a more practical approach, assume you want to impose something like the streaming API on an unknown set of implementations without having the ability to change the underlying interface.
Thanks for your opinion on this.

Comment: So you are saying all your existing Cn classes only have a default constructor? So that all of them could be subclassed that easily?

Comment: @PavneetSingh No! No! Code Review considers such questions hypothetical, which are [off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @PhilippSander See above comment. The migration will be rejected if anyone starts one, I'm certain. Code Review will not accept it.

Comment: @Mast pretty sure this is a "design pattern usage" issue

Comment: @PhilippSander His issue is irrelevant if the code is not a concrete working piece. This is way too hypothetical.

Comment: @Mast so simply OP need to follow the guidelines of code review site though answer of this post will opinion based and usually SO discourage these kind of questions although this question will not be closed unless it has 5 flags or some high repo java member close it , so meanwhile some can easily answer it

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of solving such things, is *delegation*. Since we don’t know anything about your `I` nor `C1`..`C9` types, I’ll use a commonly known interface for demonstration:

```
public interface ExtSet<T> extends Set<T> {
    default T reduce(BinaryOperator<T> op) {
        Iterator<T> it = iterator();
        T t=it.next();
        while(it.hasNext()) t=op.apply(t, it.next());
        return t;
    }
    public static <T> ExtSet<T> enhance(Set<T> set) {
        if(set instanceof ExtSet) return (ExtSet<T>)set;
        final class Enhanced extends AbstractSet<T> implements ExtSet<T> {
            public Iterator<T> iterator() { return set.iterator(); }
            public int size() { return set.size(); }
            public boolean contains(Object o) { return set.contains(o); }
            public boolean add(T e) { return set.add(e); }
            public boolean remove(Object o) { return set.remove(o); }
        }
        return new Enhanced();
    }
}
```

The delegation implementation has to do more work than an extending class with possibly empty body, but it only has to do it *once* and will work with *all* interface implementations, without even knowing them, i.e.

```
ExtSet<String> set1=ExtSet.enhance(new TreeSet<>());
Collections.addAll(set1, "foo", "bar", "baz");
System.out.println(set1.reduce(String::concat));

ExtSet<Integer> set2=ExtSet.enhance(new HashSet<>());
Collections.addAll(set2, 100, 42, 7);
System.out.println(set2.reduce(Integer::sum));

ExtSet<Thread.State> set3=ExtSet.enhance(
                              EnumSet.of(Thread.State.TERMINATED, Thread.State.NEW));
System.out.println(set3.reduce(BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

This is similar to how [`checkedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedSet-java.util.Set-java.lang.Class-), [`synchronizedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-), and [`unmodifiableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-) enhance (or restrict) an existing `Set` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't trying to "mixin" the `IX` interface, an anonymous class with an empty body would do the job.

```
IX object = new C9(){};
```

(This assumes that `C9` already implements `IX`)

Now `object` is an instance of an anonymous subclass of `C9`.

But if `C9` doesn't already implement `C9`, there is no pure Java solution apart from *modifying* `C9` ... which renders `C9X` unnecessary.

But note that modifying `C9` to also implement `IX` should be benign.  For a start, it doesn't break binary compatibility.